# Distance between two points in a new way

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

The conventional distance formula is : 
$$d= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}$$
But I have seen that there is another way in which distance is defined which is:
$$d= |x_1-x_2|+ |y_1-y_2|$$
Can someone please tell what is this form called? And also, why is it important in coordinate geometry?

Comment: This would be the distance formula used in [Taxicab Geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the Taxicab or Manhattan distance. It is useful in problems where oblique lines are not allowed.

You will find more distances here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance

Comment: Thanks for the answer